What to put in dt paremeter or "sample spacing" for pycwt's `wct()` or their wavelet coherence test function?
I am trying to create some stuff from an academic paper, and one point it requires wavelet coherence or wcoherence() from matlab.
I am required to use python so the next best alternative is pycwt library.   wct() has a compulsary dt parameter for sample spacing.
I am sorry but I am new to signal processing. It may be some fundamentals that I have skipped.
